# How to convert Gio::Menu inherited class into Gtk::widget

Tags: c++, class, gio, gtkmm4

I have the following code

```
class XMenu: public Gio::Menu
{
    public:
        XMenu();
};

class App : public Gtk::Window
{
    public:
        App();
    protected :
        Gtk::Button btn;
        XMenu menu;
};

XMenu::XMenu()
{
    append("option1", "app.option1");
    append("Quit", "app.quit");
}

App::App() 
{
    set_default_size(600,600);
    btn.set_label("Hello");
    //auto casted_menu = dynamic_cast<Gtk::Widget&>(menu);
    set_child(casted_menu);
}
```

As you can see I have two custom class one inherits from `Gio::Menu` the other from `Gtk::Window`, the goal is to create a menu bar in the App GUI by using a custom menubar created using the XMenu class, when `set_child` is commented the code compiles without errors but when uncommented the following error is thrown

```
main.cc:33:19: error: cannot convert ‘XMenu’ to ‘Gtk::Widget&’
   33 |         set_child(menu);
      |                   ^~~~
      |                   |
      |                   XMenu
```

How can I use this custom menubar in a GUI application?

If I understand correctly this states that XMenu should be a Widget in order to be added, so I tried dynamically casting it into a widget but didn't help

Comment: Have you read any documentation or at least tried any example code of gtkmm? Such large things like GUI frameworks can not be learned by random trial of typing code and compiler error. The Gio::Menu is data model readable with Gtk::Builder, you perhaps want to read it from somewhere and make Gtk::MenuBar from it.

Comment: @ÖöTiib i learning by doing the docs are a bit confusing they refer to gtkmm-3.0 but i which to use gtkmm-4.0 simply because it is newer and i am guessing it will have a longer support than gtkmm-3.0

Comment: Are you saying that gtkmm-4 docs are refering to gtkmm-3? That is normal as there is backwards compatibility, not everything changed between versions. Understanding how to use a GUI framework can not be anyway gained without reading docs.

Comment: @ÖöTiib there is a noticeable change between the two versions